# How to control the max number of row for each record in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

The table structure is:

```
user
-----
id

video
------
id

user_views
----------
id
user_id
video_id
create_date
```

And the user_views can be duplicate, to prevent the data become very huge, I would like to limit the user_views record:

**each user can record maximum 20 user_views, if exceed , it will replace the oldest record , in first in , first out manner**

The problem is , how can I structure the insert query?

Right now my approach is using PHP

1. count number of row of specific user.
2. if > 20 , update the last record (order by create_date)
3. else , insert new record

it works but I would like a more performance way that is a one insert query in MYSQL.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There is no way to do it in one INSERT query. You'd have to run a DELETE as well. They both have their own function and you can't mix them together.

Comment: Considered using triggers?

Comment: Well even with trigger it cant be done since the trigger must be `before insert` and with the condition `if > 20` it should update the same table and its not allowed in the trigger to update the same table where other trigger is getting executed.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, great input. What about stored procedures to insert/update/delete - and only grant select privilege to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: Create dummy records so as to *always* have 20 views per user.

```
insert into user_views (user_id, video_id, create_date)
select id, null, '1920-01-01' from user u
where (select count(*) from user_views uv where uv.user_id = u.id) < 20
union all
select id, null, '1919-01-01' from user u
where (select count(*) from user_views uv where uv.user_id = u.id) < 19
union all
select id, null, '1918-01-01' from user u
where (select count(*) from user_views uv where uv.user_id = u.id) < 18
union all
select id, null, '1917-01-01' from user u
where (select count(*) from user_views uv where uv.user_id = u.id) < 17
union all
...
```

When selecting the data in order to show them, exclude the dummy records:

```
select *
from user_views
where user_id = 123
and video_id is not null; -- dummy entries have video_id null
```

When "inserting" new data, use UPDATE:

```
update user_views
set video_id = 456, create_date = current_date()
where id = 
(
  select id 
  from
  (
    select id 
    from user_views
    where user_id = 123
    order by create_date
    limit 1
  ) oldest
);
```

(The subquery in the subquery is needed in MySQL because of a limitation when accessing the same table that is being updated.)

SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11f2c4/1.